# When I set PhpStorm theme to Darcula directory and file names in the side bar becomes invisible

Tags: phpstorm

So when I switch to Darcula on Ubuntu 14.04, the sidebar dir and file  names disappear. If I highlight they do appear again, so i suppose the font names are in same color as the background. How could I solve this?

Comment: 1) Did you change both GUI Theme and Editor scheme to Darcula? 2) Do you use VCS in this project? 3) Have you tried restarting IDE after making these changes?

Comment: 1, not sure which one I changed, but only changed one thing. 2. Yes,  SVN. 3. Nope. I will try tomorrow, not at work tomorrow.

Comment: VCS/File Status colors are part of the Editor color schema -- if you choose incompatible one then it may conflict with dark GUI theme (Darcula). I may suggest: reset both to standard/default and restart IDE; Now change both to Darcula. If still nothing -- show screenshots.

Answer (score 5):

Restart the application, worked for me. 
If that doesn't work, make sure both the GUI Theme and Editor are configured to the Darcula theme and restart again.

Comment: As silly as it may be, this will actually be the correct answer for some. Even though the IDE changes the colours of the UI and editor panel on the spot without restarting, changes to the terminal and file explorer panels need an IDE restart - this can be misleading.